# PHP: Date formatting using "Y-m-d H:i"

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Why the first sample code works fine, while the second one produces an error?

`SolDate` is equal to 2010-10-10, and `depT` 10:15:00, and `arrT` 11:30:15. I'm using the function `strtotime` to cut out seconds from `depT` and `arrT`.

**1st**

```
$i = 0;
    foreach ($result1 as $row):
        $data[] = array($i,array('xxx','yyy','zzz'),
        "2010-10-10 10:15",
        "2010-10-10 11:30");
        $i++;
    endforeach;
```

**2nd**

```
$i = 0;
        foreach ($result1 as $row):
            $data[] = array($i,array('xxx','yyy','zzz'),
            date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($row['SolDate'] . ' ' . $row['depT'])),
            date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($row['SolDate'] . ' ' . $row['arrT'])));
            $i++;
        endforeach;
```

I'm using this code for creating jpGraph Gantt Chart. The problem is that 1st method generates the Gantt chart, while the 2nd method produces the following error message:

> JpGraph Error 6007: Sanity check for automatic Gantt chart size failed. Either the width (=1348) or height(=35667) is larger than MAX_GANTTING_SIZE.

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using braces around your loop block? Also what specifically doesn't work?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Using `strtotime()` for what is basically string manipulation is inefficient overkill. I would just `explode()`/`array_pop()`, `strstr()`, or `substr()`/`strpos()` if I were you...

Comment: Please look at the update of my thread.

Comment: What do you get if you put "print_r($data); exit();" after the code you've posted? The error may become very obvious if you examine the contents of $data before you use them. The bug doesn't appear to be in the code you've posted. Where is $result1 coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't clear as you're using 2010-10-10, but on the 2nd example you have `date("Y-m-m ...")` on the 5th line. Could this be throwing the error?

Comment: Oh, there should be Y-m-d. Sorry, mistyping.